# How to create a report for each?

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I want to create a report for each order with the bootstrap modal. How do I do this?

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-action="{{ route('admin.orders.report', $order->id) }}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#report" data-id="{{ $order->id }}">Report</button>
```

script

```js
$('#report').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
  var action = button.data('action');
  var orderId = button.data('id');
  var modal = $(this);
  modal.find('form').attr('action', action);
  document.getElementById("orderId").value = orderId;
});
```

web.php

```php
Route::get('orders/report/{order}', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\OrderController::class, 'report'])->name('orders.report');
```

Controller

```php
public function report(Order $order)
{
  return view('Admin.orders.pdf', compact('order'));
}
```

modal

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="report" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="report" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form action="{{ route('admin.orders.report', $order->id) }}" method="post">
        @csrf
        <input id="orderIdUn" type="hidden" name="order_id" value="">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Yes</button>
```

I see this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: Error tells you that no element has the id of `orderId`

Comment: If you wish to use the `var orderId` then you need to do `document.getElementById(orderId)`

Comment: What's the solution?

Comment: There is still no ID ``orderId``...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't assign the mentioned id to any element. Change this:

```
<input id="orderIdUn" type="hidden" name="order_id" value="">
```

to this:

```
<input id="orderId" type="hidden" name="order_id" value="">
```

And because you specified the method in your form to `POST` you have to change your route method to `POST` too (It could be `GET` but it's safer this way). In `web.php` file:

```
Route::post('orders/report/{order}', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\OrderController::class, 'report'])->name('orders.report');
```

Comment: I get this error. `The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.`

Comment: This guy is famous on Laracasts as Oxbir... It was really hard to change `orderIdUn` to `orderId` right? Unbelievable.

Comment: @MichalOravec 